# Creating menu system using int, do-while and if

Tags: java

I tried making a menu system to make a user select between four options. To distinguish between the selections I check the int entered. It works but somehow I feel it is not very elegant. Especially when I set the initial value of selectedMenu to 1902475424 to check for when the user entered a mismatcing value. I assumed the user wont accidentally type  1902475424.

Is there a way more simple way to make a menu system or will this do? Is this major flawed?

Yes im a beginner to Java :-)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Menu {

    public void printMenu() {
        System.out.println(
                "1. Start new game\n" + 
                "2. Load game\n" + 
                "3. Settings\n" + 
                "4. Exit\n"
        );
    }

    public void selectMenu() throws InputMismatchException {
        int selectedMenu = 1902475424;
        Scanner aScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            selectedMenu = 1902475424;
            try {
                System.out.println("Try block begin.");
                selectedMenu = aScanner.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Catch blok begin.");
                System.out
                        .println("Invalid input, please input a number between 1-4.");
                aScanner.nextLine();
            }
            if ((selectedMenu < 1 || selectedMenu > 4)
                    && (selectedMenu != 1902475424)) {
                System.out.println("Input out of range \"" + selectedMenu
                        + "\". Input a number between 1-4.");
            }
        } while (selectedMenu == 1902475424
                || (selectedMenu < 1 || selectedMenu > 4));

        if (selectedMenu >= 1 && selectedMenu <= 4) {
            System.out.println("A new game will now start.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the flag value as a final variable outside your method (static or otherwise) and reference it in your method. `private static final int FLAG_VALUE = 1902475424;`, so that if you ever change it, you only need to change it in one place. `int selectedMenu = FLAG_VALUE;`. But honestly, you don't need to check for it. If you initialize it to 0 at the start and then check for <1 and >4 in your while, you'll be fine.

Comment: since 1902475424 is greater than 4, there's not need to explicitly check for it in addition to checking that the value is greater than or equal to 1 and less than or equal to 4.  As a matter of fact, you could just use 5 instead of 1902475424

Comment: Simple `0` or `-1` as flag for bad choice would be enough and easier to handle.

Comment: This is kindda interesting. `FLAG` for bad choice will also take care of rollover of integers

Comment: Thanks! This explains a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is leaning into the *overkill* category :]
You can do away with your random value of `1902475424` like so:

```
public void selectMenu() throws InputMismatchException {
    int selectedMenu;
    Scanner aScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("Try block begin.");
            selectedMenu = aScanner.nextInt();
            if(selectedMenu < 1 || selectedMenu > 4) {
                System.out.println("Input out of range \"" + selectedMenu + "\". Input..");
            }
        } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Catch blok begin.");
            System.out.println("Invalid input, please input a number between 1-4.");
            aScanner.nextLine();
            selectedMenu = 0;
        } 

    } while(selectedMenu < 1 || selectedMenu > 4);

    System.out.println("A new game will now start.");
}
```

Comment: `&&` will make more sense than `||`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I can see how this is much simpler, reading this I'm not even sure why I did use that random value, thanks! :)

Comment: @smit It's `||` because you're checking outside the bounds of a range.

Comment: I think it should be ||, else none of the if and while will ever trigger. The value can't at the same time both be higher and lower than the range 1-4, so it must be either? oh you already wrote that :)

Comment: -------------- to be deleted

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following alternative (pseudocode):

```
int getMenuOption() {
    print(message)
    read(input)

    if input is valid then return input
    else then return getMenuOption()
}
```

This is recursive, so if the user sits there and enters bad numbers long enough, you could overflow the stack. You could easily augment this to give the user a fixed number of tries:

```
int getMenuOption(int triesRemaining) {
    if (triesRemaining == 0) throw new RetriesExceededException();

    print(message)
    read(input)

    if input is valid then return input
    else then return getMenuOption(triesRemaining - 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a revision to the `selectMenu()` method you provided that should get the job done! I tested it out and it seems to work as expected. :)

```
public void selectMenu() {

    int selectedMenuItem = 0;
    Scanner aScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(selectedMenuItem == 0){

        String userInputMenuItemString = aScanner.nextLine();

        try {
            int userInputMenuItem = Integer.parseInt(userInputMenuItemString);
            if(userInputMenuItem > 0 && userInputMenuItem <= 4){

                selectedMenuItem = userInputMenuItem;

            }else{

                System.out.println("No option #" + Integer.toString(userInputMenuItem) + " exists!\nTry again:");

            }
        } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {

            System.out.println("Please input a number!");

        }

    }

    switch(selectedMenuItem){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("You chose to start a new game!");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("You chose to load a game!");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("You chose to access settings!");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("You chose to exit. Bye!");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: But wont it crash in case of mismatching input, when you dont use try-catch?

Comment: Good call. I overlooked that in your code. I'll revise the code for that! :)

Comment: @user1949930 Okay. I made the necessary changes to catch the exception. It uses a different way of retrieving the integer from the user, but this way allows for more flexibility, and doesn't add any length to the code.

Comment: @user1949930 no problem! Glad I could help. Want to mark this one (or whichever one helped most) the answer to close the topic?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that (I haven't tested it)

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.InputMismatchException;

    public class Menu {

            public void printMenu() {
                    System.out.println("1. Start new game\n" + "2. Load game\n"
                                    + "3. Settings\n" + "4. Exit\n");
            }

            public void selectMenu() throws InputMismatchException {
                    int selectedMenu;
                    boolean validSelection = false;
                    Scanner aScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                    while(!validSelection) {
                            selectedMenu = aScanner.nextInt();
                            validSelection = true;
                            switch (selectedMenu) {
                                    case 1:
                                            // doWhen1();
                                            break;
                                    case 2:
                                            // doWhen2();
                                            break;
                                    case 3:
                                            // doWhen3();
                                            break;
                                    case 4:
                                            // doWhen4();
                                            break;
                                    default:
                                            System.out.println("Input out of range \"" + selectedMenu
                                                    + "\". Input a number between 1-4.");
                                            validSelection = false;
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```